# Remove Git Unpublish option in VS 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I absolutely HATE the unpublish option for items in Git on VS 2013.  I have frequently, because of a muscle spasm or other issue, accidently clicked on unpublish when trying to switch to a branch in VS 2013.  If the branch hadn't been pulled recently, all remote changes are lost upon republishing the branch.  This is horrible when working on something like a "release" branch.

Is there some way to disable the unpublish option in VS 2013?  Or at least make it prompt me with a "This is destructive, are you sure?"

Comment: Unpublish actually isn't destructive. it's just that you can't see the branch anymore, it still exists in the server side git repository. You can simply restore the remote branch from the commandline and publish it back to the server. Unpublishing a branch is a similar to removing a Tag or Label. The changes are still there, just no longer easy to find by the Tag or label name.

Comment: I have to disagree a little. I think it can be destructive. Let's say user 1 has pulled branch release/1 down from the server. User 2 also pulls down the branch.  User 1 branches off his local branch, does some work and publishes his new bugfix branch. Pull requests are done, the branch is merged back into the release/1 branch.  User 1 is in talking to release management to delploy his code. Now, user 2 has not done a fetch/pull to get the latest updates to the release/1 branch.  He accidentally clicks unpublish. Realizing his mistake, he publishes the branch back. User 1 changes are now lost.

Comment: Lost from a standpoint of release management, expecting to see them in the branch, doesn't see them anymore. Sure, the bugfix can be merged back in, but this is just 1 item. Imagine that user 2 hadn't pulled down several updates.   Very time consuming to have to figure out what was lost.

Comment: The changes are still not lost. If you'd fetch the commit hash of the first users commit you'll see they're still there. Yes you'd have to merge them with dev b's code probably, but this is not destructive. You could always secure the branches once created...

Comment: That's the problem. Imagine dozens of commits that now have to be tracked down and determined if they were lost, sometimes covering several branches. While not "destructive" it is time consuming and a loss of productivity. There really needs to be an "are you sure" on this. Or at least a fetch first to see if there are changes first.

Comment: One more thing I dislike about VS. Absolutely agree with destructiveness. Solutions that come to my mind: 1)Assign hotkeys to useful actions and never use GUI directly 2) Add buttons for useful actions onto some hotbar 3) always use commandline and hide all VCS-related bars in VS.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to remove this behavior in Visual Studio 2013. But it seems that Microsoft has heard your feedback, in the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 the whole Branches experience has been reworked and there is a confirmation on <kbd>Unpublish</kbd>.

[image]

As I mentioned in the comments, the unpublish command is not destructive, in that it destroys the changes made. Should you accidentally unpublish a branch, you can either republish it from your local repository and then see whether there are commits trailing your last version, then fast-forward. This is indeed not ideal, but if you do it directly after making the mistake, it won't be as dramatic as you describe it to be. A nuisance: absolutely. End of the world: no.

To protect yourself from these issues, you could go into the Web Access module and deny the administer branch permission a for most users. This prevents accidental branch deletion, but does also take away a few other permissions:

[image]

For more information on Branch Security, check out:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#Git